# Should I use "could" or "would" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

> Life is unpredictable. For instance, he
> **wouldn't** have guessed he **would** win the lottery.
>
> Life is unpredictable. For instance, he
> **couldn't** have guessed he **could** win the lottery.

I'm a little confused. Both sound good to me (with a slight preference to would).

Comment: Well, did he win the lottery?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**...wouldn't/couldn't have guessed...**

Using "**w**ouldn't have guessed" gives the meaning that it would be unexpected (an **improbability**) for him to guess that he would win the lottery.

Using "**c**ouldn't have guessed" gives the meaning that it would be impossible (an **inability**) for him to guess that he would win the lottery.

I would choose *couldn't* in this sentence because the intended meaning is not so much that he was *unlikely* to guess, but that he was *unable* to guess (or, more accurately, *know*) that he would win the lottery.

**...would/could win the lottery.**

Using "**w**ould win the lottery" means that he, in fact, went on to win the lottery. In other words, *would* is used in this context to express something either happening or not happening.

Using "**c**ould win the lottery" means that it is **possible** for him to win the lottery, but does not tell whether he did or didn't win.

Of these two, I would choose *would* in this sentence because the intended meaning is not that he had no idea it was possible for him to win the lottery, but that he had no idea it was going to happen.

> Life is unpredictable. For instance, he **couldn't** have guessed he **would** win the lottery.

Comment: Also, avoiding the repetition makes the sentence sound better.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably word it, "Life is unpredictable. For instance, he **couldn't** have guessed he **would** win the lottery."  Why?  Because "could/couldn't" means he was or was not able to guess or win, whereas "would/woudln't" means he did or did not guess or win.  Essentially:

> "*Earlier on*, he was **not able** to guess that he, *before now*, **did** win the lottery."

That being said, native speakers don't usually make too big a deal out of could/would in situations like this...though in this particular situation, there is a difference between whether you **can** win a lottery and whether you **do** win the lottery.